# Testing if a controller renders a JS Template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def enable_password_change
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {
        render :layout => false
      }
    end
  end
end
```

And the following test:

```
test "should render js to show the change password form" do
  sign_in_user
  request_javascript
  get :enable_password_change
  assert_template :enable_password_change
  assert_response :ok
end
```

And the helper method to set the request headers:

```
def request_javascript
  @request.headers["Accepts"] = "text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript"
end
```

However my test reports:

```
Finished tests in 0.942294s, 7.4287 tests/s, 15.9186 assertions/s.

1) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_render_js_to_show_the_change_password_for:
ActionController::UnknownFormat: ActionController::UnknownFormat
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:9:in `enable_password_change'
test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'

7 tests, 15 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the the xml_http_request or alias xhr for that

```
test "should render js to show the change password form" do
   sign_in_user

   xhr :get, :enable_password_change

   assert_template :enable_password_change
   assert_response :ok
   assert assigns(:merchant_user)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In an instance of TestCase, #get calls #process which calls @request.recycle! which sets @request.headers to an empty hash. To test a js response, I think you'll have to have the test fire up a browser with Selenium or something like that.